# Does Rufus save one's data better or different than UNetbootin when reinstalling from USB?

Tags: rufus, reinstalling

I really need to retrieve data of my other laptop and can wait no longer for my friend to come help. Reading up on the process (I'm stuck in emergency mode) I am slightly confused if I need to use Rufus instead of UNetbootin when reinstalling from USB.

Comment: Rufus and Unetbootin do not save any data.

Comment: @mikewhatever [Starting with Ubuntu 19.10, persistent partitions can be added to UNetbootin and Rufus and also to cloned drives.](https://askubuntu.com/a/1176431/)

Answer (score 3):

There are basically two alternatives to retrieve the data of your other laptop using a USB boot drive.

### Live-only USB boot drive

- Run the USB boot drive **live (live-only)** and retrieve the data of your other laptop into an third drive, for example a USB hard disk drive or SSD.

  In this case you can use 'any' tool to create the USB boot drive.

  - In Ubuntu it is easiest to use the **Startup Disk Creator**.
  - In Windows you can use both tools that you suggest in the question, **Rufus** and **Unetbootin**. Both are good tools.
  - In MacOS **Unetbootin** is a good alternative.

### Persistent live USB boot drive

- Run the USB boot drive **persistent live** and retrieve the data of your other laptop into the USB boot drive itself.

  In this case I would recommend the methods described at [**this link**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181854/how-is-it-easier-to-make-a-persistent-live-drive-with-ubuntu-19-10), particularly the methods to get a `casper-rw` **partition** (and use the whole drive space),

  - [mkusb in Linux](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) with all current versions of Ubuntu iso files
  - [HxD + Win32 Disk Imager in Windows](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb) with the Ubuntu 19.10 iso file

---

If you use a method that creates a `casper-rw` **file**, it will be limited to 4 GiB which is the maximum file size in a FAT32 file system.