# Not able to clone Ubuntu 22.04 on USB using Clonezilla

Tags: usb, clonezilla, cloning

Successfully created Ubuntu 22.04 USB disk after following the tutorial at:
[How to Create a Full Install of Ubuntu 22.04 to USB Device Step by Step](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403792/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-22-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step)

To create full backup of the USB I am selecting drive to image backup option in Clonezilla ..the first, unformatted 1 MB partition i.e. sdf2 (labelled as BIOS in the image) is not cloned as filesystem is unknown.

If this partition is needed for proper booting of  UEFI Ubuntu USB, then please suggest how to configure Clonezilla so that this partition is also cloned? Or any other method?

Comment: My experience with Clonezilla is that it can clone also the unformatted 1 MB partition (which I guess is the `bios_grub` partition) You should need no extra setting for that to happen, only 'drive to image'. It should use crude cloning with dd for that purpose. But that partition is only needed for booting in BIOS mode (alias CSM alias legacy mode) and it is not necessary in UEFI mode.

Comment: Installed latest (alternative stable - 20220620-jammy) clonezilla on GPT-UEFI USB and booted from it ...selected device to image; expert mode with switches -e2 -c -j2 -cs etc. also bzip2 compression with default partition copy type ...any changes in switches or partition copy type (say DD) needed for saving the 1 mb partition?

Comment: I don't know, I always use 'beginner mode'. It is enough for me. I should also mention that I use the 'stable' series (Debian based Clonezilla iso files). But I think that should make no difference concerning how to manage the unformatted 1 MB partition (which I guess is the bios_grub partition). -- What happens when you run Clonezilla? Will it finish or stop too early? Will the result be useful? Please realize that you should not rely on a backup method, that is not tested, so test it by restoring to a fresh drive and boot the computer from that drive.

Comment: Yeah thanks beginner mode works! May be that some switch in expert mode was not able to read or perform 256 checksum on the 1 MB bios_grub partition. Yep I will verify by restoring it on another USB ..things may get messy; specially due to bad sectors on the media.

Comment: Good luck @ls_milkyway  :-)