# How would I use both Legacy (BIOS) and UEFI in the same Ubuntu installation

Tags: system-installation

I am installing Ubuntu on a external drive and I need said drive to have support for Legacy (BIOS) and UEFI machines. Without going into too much information **WHY** I want to do this, lets just say it would be less of a headache to have one installation for both booting methods in case I find a computer that has one but not the other.

and yes, I have googled all I can and have tried for the last 20 hours to do this with either booting in Legacy (MBR) correctly or UEFI correctly, but not both. One ending with a blinking underscore and an unbootable system.

**tl**;**dr**: I want to boot my Ubuntu installation on both Legacy (BIOS) and UEFI machines.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Create a Full Install of Ubuntu 20.04 to USB Device Step by Step](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step) It covers both legacy BIOS and UEFI.

Comment: Yes! I am sorry for the duplicate question. N00b here, thank you for answering my question!

Comment: There are some small differences between installing 20.04 and 22.04. For 22.04 see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403792/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-22-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step