# Configure USB boot to load Linux from hard drive

Tags: boot, grub2, usb

I have a Lenovo Thinkstation E30.  I cannot get it to boot from the hard drive and have given up trying.  My thought now is to boot from a USB stick and have it load Ubuntu from the hard drive (or even load from the USB) and mount / from the hard drive.  How do I modify the Ubuntu install image to do this?  I've tried to

`chroot /cdrom`,

but I get

`failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory`.

I don't know how to make this work.  Since it can boot from USB, I think I need to have grub mount the hard drive, then add a menu option to `/cdrom/boot/grub/grub.cfg` to have it load **vmlinuz** from the hard drive.  Other than the theory, I have no idea how to do any of this in reality.  (Another option might be to load Linux from the USB and mess with /etc/init.d stuff to load a chrooted Linux from the hard drive.)

Answer (score 2):

### Boot Ubuntu from Internal Hard Drive or from USB

- Install Ubuntu to Internal Hard Drive.
- Full install Ubuntu to the USB Drive, see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1403793/43926
- Boot USB drive and in Terminal run: `sudo update-grub`

The internal Ubuntu install will be added to the USB's GRUB menu. You can then boot either install of Ubuntu from the USB or you can delete everything except partitions 2 and 3 if you just want the internal install and do not need to use the Ubuntu on the USB.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it with Ubuntu, but with AlmaLinux was able to create a bootable live image for a USB stick.

Booting Ubuntu a live image on the USB stick should allow you to investigate the state of the installation on the hard drive and/or re-install onto the hard drive.

If you haven't seen it, [Try Ubuntu before you install it](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started) has links to tutorials for creating a bootable USB stick.