# How to make ubuntu 22.04 use their own efi system partition when dual boot with windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

When i install ubuntu 22.04 alongside windows 10, my windows 10 has its own efi partition with 100MB in size, i create 1GB efi partition for ubuntu (after i see common size for efi ubuntu is 550MB) but after finishing installation my ubuntu /boot/efi is mounted efi folder  on efi partiton of windows. So can someone show me the way to make ubuntu use my given efi partition

Comment: You need only one `efi` partition.

Comment: but i see recomended size for efi on ubuntu is 550 mb while windows only need 100mb, and i want to separate efi btw these two os to make sure one things has errors dont affect another

Comment: It is OK to have 100 MB for both. It is a bad idea to "separate" them.

Comment: i dont know why this idea is not good, can you tell me some problems when i do that

Comment: The problem is that you have one UEFI.

Comment: You can only have one EFI partition per disk. If you have two only one will be usable. If you have a second disk you can have one EFI partition on that in addition to the EFI partition on the first disk. In that case you choose which EFI partition to use by choosing which disk to boot from.

Comment: My machine allows me to add boot option, when I have new efi folder to boot, i only need to add it and choose it as first boot

Comment: If you make an install with one EFI partition you can choose in the Grub menu which OS you like to boot. I believe though OS-prober in Grub is disabled in 22.04 and 22.10. Just enable it and you're good to go. Why make 2 EFI's and complicate things? Only to be able to choose in the UEFI which OS to boot? Beware: with major Windows updates it will take over the bootloader again.

Comment: My Windows computer has Ubuntu installed without an Ubuntu bootloader. I have created a separate Ubuntu Full install USB. I booted from the USB and in Terminal ran `sudo update-grub` . This put the internal installation of Ubuntu on the USB's boot menu. I can now boot Windows from it's own bootloader and Ubuntu from the USB. For Full install USB see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1403793/43926