# How to create a bootable ubuntu thumbdrive with preferences intact?

Tags: dual-boot

I want to keep all my GUI changes and softwares installed with their preferences intact when I boot into another system using a bootable thumb drive.

Comment: SS Drive, HD Drive, and Flash Drive can all have Full Ubuntu installed, See https://askubuntu.com/q/1403792/43926

Comment: My changes to ubuntu will also be installed onto the flash drive? Is there a way to form an ubuntu installation file of my specific setup also. Not simply the out-of-the-box ubuntu?

Comment: A Full install to Flash drive is just like a Full install to SSD but a little slower. You can add the ability to use the drive for installation. See: https://askubuntu.com/q/1300540/43926

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Create a Full Install of Ubuntu 22.04 to USB Device Step by Step](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403792/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-22-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step)

Comment: Since I have made alterations to the original Ubuntu installed on system(preferences, GUI etc.) Is there a way to create the flash drive which will also automatically install my preferences etc., without me having to do all those changes manually once again?