# Why does Ubuntu installer add 33MB of free space at beginning of disk and why is EFI partition 469MB in size vs 512MB?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

Installing Ubuntu for desktops 22.04.1 LTS on an external 16GB SSD and trying to make sense of following inconsistencies?

1. create new partition table

   [image: New partition table]
2. create 512MB EFI partition

   [image: EFI]
3. create 15511MB ext4 partition

   [image: ext4]
4. check if everything is OK before installing

   [image: Install now]

Why does Ubuntu installer add 33MB at beginning of disk? Why is EFI partition 469MB vs 512MB?

Comment: I can't tell you why the nstaller does this but there's a way to go around this problem. During a live session, open gparted and prepare the drive with the partitions you need at correct locations, then use the installer with `something else` to select the prepared partitions for installation.

Comment: Is your / partition 10GB or is it 15.5GB. 10GB seems a little light to me. Myself, I don't create any partitions like you created sda1. I would just select sda and then "+" then fill out the information. I have made step by step instructions for a Full install USB device you may find useful: https://askubuntu.com/q/1403792/43926

Comment: @David, why did you remove screenshots?

Comment: They add no additional info to the text in the question and slow the loading and display of the question.

Comment: @David Screenshots were OK. I rolled it back.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Where is 10GB / referenced?

Comment: "Step 3: create 10000MB ext4 partition". Am I reading this wrong? Nice screen shots they add a lot.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Thanks for reporting typo… question updated.