# How can i install ubuntu 22.04 LTS easily using usb flash drive?

Tags: boot, grub2, usb

Before i tried to install ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my laptop, it's now running windows 10. But almost the last step i found a problem "Grub Rescue". I tried to fix that "Grub rescue" problem using command but i was unable to fix it. After many attempts when i was unable,  i took my laptop to a mechanic and he again install windows 10, and that's how i fix my problem. But still, i want to use ubuntu without windows 10, so please give me the detail guidelines how can i run ubuntu easily step by step facing no error or problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: 1. What computer is it? Please tell us the brand name and model of the a: computer itself and the brand name and model of the b: graphics chip/card; 2. Please tell us also how you made the USB drive bootable (which tool/method you used); 3. Please check with sha256sum that the download was successful, that the iso file is good.

Comment: See these 2 links. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: If you are running Windows try creating your USB installer using Ventoy, Etcher, or Rufus, (I think Rufus is not yet working with Ubuntu 23.04). Install Ubuntu in the same BIOS/UEFI mode Windows is booting in. You can't break your Windows disk if you remove it and install Ubuntu on a second disk, either internal or USB. See: https://askubuntu.com/a/1403793/43926

Comment: https://dellwindowsreinstallationguide.com/ubuntu-23-04/ Read this before trying Rufus with Ubuntu 23.04

Comment: "*please give me the detail guidelines how can i run ubuntu easily step by step facing no error or problem*" Instead you must learn how to handle the grub rescue prompt. For most users the existing installer works properly, so something about your system is unusual.

Comment: The information you're asking for already exists in the form of an [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop). However, as a prerequisite, you must have the knowledge to operate your own hardware/firmware. Specifically, you need to know how to boot a USB flash drive on your particular motherboard. If you don't know how to do this, you'll need to research the documentation for your motherboard or use the support options available for your particular hardware. If you still encounter problems, please reference the tutorial when asking so we know where you're stuck