# how to make ubuntu live usb contains spasific apps and my wifi driver

Tags: wireless, live-usb, iso, boot-repair

I want to make ubuntu live usb or iso file contains my spasific apps like as boot-repair, malicious removal, internet explorer and my wifi driver (bcm43xx). the reason is every time i have to install them after boot by usb flash drive to fix or tray some thing. thanks to all participants.

Comment: For wifi do you have to install firmware-b43-installer?

Comment: @Jeremy31 yes but i add wifi driver manualy by offline installation or connect my phone by usb for firmware-b43-installer online installation

Comment: I think CUBIC can make custom ISO's but I haven't used it https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2023/02/cubic-is-a-custom-ubuntu-iso-creator

Comment: thanks @Jeremy31, i will tray it and tell you.

Comment: Why not just a full install to another flash drive. Or better to an external SSD which makes for a very fast system.

Comment: A Full install to USB is just like an install to internal disk, just a little slower. As oldfred says an install to USB SSD is very fast. See https://askubuntu.com/q/1403792/43926

Comment: @karel no it is talking about full installation but my question about live usb or iso file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three wayes that i trayed them

### make a "Persistent Live System" USB by **mkusb**

"**mkusb** a safe tool to create a bootable drive from an iso image or a compressed image file.[1](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

installation:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository universe # only for standard Ubuntu live
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa # and press Enter
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install mkusb
$ sudo apt install mkusb usb-pack-efi
```

The following command is an alternative for systems without a graphic environment for example Ubuntu Server

```
sudo apt install dus mkusb-nox
```

[installation instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

The tool has a command line version and a GUI version.
You can launch the GUI version from Ubuntu's Dock by selecting the "guidus" app.[2](https://answers.launchpad.net/cubic/+question/694592)

1. Launch guidus or mkusb from launcher
2. Select i Install (make a boot device)
3. Select p 'Persistent live' - only Debian and Ubuntu
4. Select sdb (or whatever is your USB disk) play more attention in this step to make sure you realy select usb drive not hard drive.
5. Move the slider to select free space you want (80% is good for a 4-8GB USB stick)
6. Select Go

   **[mkUSB-quick-start-manual-22.pdf](https://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/mkusb/mkUSB-quick-start-manual-22.pdf)**

   this is my Persistent Live System after some customization

   [image]

### make live usb from my current operating system by systemback

I created a live usb/installation from my system’s file and all my configurations by the [Systemback](https://launchpad.net/systemback) utility.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nemh/systemback/ubuntu jammy main"
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install systemback
```

this is screenshot of my usb drive that crated by systemback
[image]

### Make filesystem.squashfs from Ubuntu root partition

We can make **filesystem.squashfs** from **Ubuntu** root partition as a backup so we can restore our Ubuntu and we can make Ubuntu live USB by this file.

1. boot by Ubuntu live USB
2. mount Ubuntu partition to `/mnt`

`sudo -i`

`mount -o ro /dev/sdax /mnt    # replace x with your (ubuntu) target partition`

3. mount other partition to save the file

`mkdir sdaz`

```
`mount /dev/sdaz  sdaz  # replace z with your (non Ubuntu) partition`
```

4. make the filesystem.squashfs

`mksquashfs /mnt/* /sdaz/filesystem.squashfs`

5. from now you have the file that will help
6. by **rufus** creat live USB by any ubuntu ISO and replace the `filesystem.squashfs` in the USB with your one.
7. frome now you can reboot by your Ubuntu live USB
8. to restore your Ubuntu partition from `filesystem.squashfs`, boot by your live USB, mount Ubuntu partiton, delete all files from Ubuntu partition mount folder, mount `filesystem.squashfs`, copy all files from filesystem.squashfs mount folder to Ubuntu partiton mount folder and reboot.


   I test all of them today, i delete all Ubuntu files and extracted `filesystem.squashfs` to root and rebooted to my Ubuntu. by my live USB that created by **rufus** i can login after write my pass word.


   **3rd way related problem**: after reboot to Ubuntu or live USB may be you will face `"You do not have the permissions necessary to view the...."` when opening some partitions that solved with me by mount any partition in `/mnt`


   **3rd way note**: make sure you have same kernel in your `filesystem.squashfs` and your other iso file that used by rufus