# Booting from External SSD

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my external SSD. I needed to create the partitions myself. Now, after copying *.efi from my GRUB installation, it still won't boot. I tried directly booting from bootx64.efi and grubx64.efi, to no avail. Windows advanced reboot also doesn't recognize it, as well as my UEFI/BIOS startup menu.
Anyone know how to fix?

Comment: is your efi partition marked as bootable? did you actually install a bootloader to the drive?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1403793/43926 for USB drive that boots both BIOS and UEFI

Comment: You need both /EFI/ubuntu & /EFI/Boot as full install boots from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi using drive entry like live installer, but need the 3 line grub.cfg in /EFI/ubuntu to find the full grub in your install. did you update fstab with UUID of external drive's ESP? `lsblk -f` If UUID correct you can just reinstall grub `sudo grub-install` which will use all default parameters.

Comment: I moved the `Boot` and `ubuntu` folders into a new `EFI` folder. Now my BIOS detects it's there, but it restarts when I tried to boot.