# How to create a bootable USB stick that runs Ubuntu Studio

Tags: live-usb

I would like to try out Ubuntu Studio without actually installing it. I downloaded Ubuntustudio-22.04.3-dvd.amd64 to my PC running Windows.  I have a USB stick formatted to FAT 32 capacity 28.9 GB. How can I create a bootble USB Flash Drive that runs Ubuntu Studio?

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/q/1403792/43926

Comment: There are also installation instructions right on the Ubuntu Studio download page...

Comment: You can use 'any' cloning tool to create a live (live-only) Ubuntu Studio system, that works well for testing, but writes to RAM, so nothing will be saved after shutdown and/or reboot. There are also other methods (than cloning) to make a live drive. In Windows you can install and use [Rufus](https://rufus.ie) or [Balena Etcher](https://etcher.balena.io/). If you already have an Ubuntu system, you can use the built-in **Startup Disk Creator** or install and use [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb).

Answer (score 1):

There are detailed instructions on the download page in the Ubuntu studio official website.

link here: https://ubuntustudio.org/download/

The download page has detailed instructions for Try before Installing and Boot from USB Stick.

If you do not complete Install Ubuntu Studio during the experience, the actual installation will not occur. After exiting, remove the USB stick and restart the computer, and the system will return to windows.

Any follow-up questions are welcome to **Ask Ubuntu**.