# Burn ISO to USB stick

Tags: iso

I am using Ubuntu 23.10 and do not have a CD/DVD reader/writer on my laptop. I have downloaded a bootable ISO from Linux Welt and want to burn this onto a USB stick but I cannot find a GUI that can do this. I have tried Startup Disk Creator, Brasero and k3b but they all seem want to write the ISO onto a CD/DVD. How can I write the bootable ISO onto the USB stick?

Comment: Have you plugged the USB stick in before starting Startup Disk Creator? It absolutely is for writing to a USB key, not a CD ROM.

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/q/1403792/43926

Comment: @popey Yes I have.

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview

Comment: Would whoever downvoted this perfectly reasonable question please enlighten us with their reasoning.

Comment: use `dd' command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to insert the USB stick and open "Disks" from the activities menu. Then click on the USB stick and then the cog and select "reinstall partition image" (my OS is German, maybe the wording is slightly diffent in English) and select the ISO you want to install.

A new user posted a link to a youtube video with this solution yesterday but his post has been removed. I can't help feeling this was a bit harsh considering he was new here his post actually helped me with my problem.

BTW the other solutions offered don't work with a USB stick on my 23.10 OS, as I stated in the OP.

Answer (score -1):

have a look at [etcher](https://etcher.balena.io/#download-etcher). It is available for most used operating systems.