# "Missing Operating System" when booting with "Live USB"

Tags: boot, live-usb, ssd

I'm trying to create a live Ubuntu OS on a 512gb SSD (mSATA drive inserted into a USB-interface housing). I've tried to create the live USB using several software (Universal USB Installer; Unetbootin) and file formats (FAT32/NTFS).

However, whenever I try to boot up the PC with the USB SSD it always says "Missing Operating System". Live USB works fine when it is installed into a 16gb pen drive but I somehow can't get it to work on the USB SSD. I wonder if anyone knows what is the reason behind?

Details are as follows:

- OS I have access to: Windows 10 (on another PC)
- OS to be installed: Ubuntu 18.04.3
- Motherboard: Gigabyte Z68P-DS3
- There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the USB-SSD
- With LinuxLive USB Creator the USB SSD doesn't show up at all. (Is that because it is classified as a harddrive rather than a pen drive?)

---

Edit: I got pass the bug using Rufus. However, Rufus itself seems to have a bug which doesn't allow live USB with persistence for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. As I wish to use the OS on-the-go, having a drive with no persistence would not be useful =(.

Comment: When you say you want to "create a live Ubuntu OS on a 512gb SSD" do you mean you want to use that Ubuntu Live SSD to fully install Ubuntu on to another drive?

Comment: It's not a Rufus bug. It's a [longstanding Ubuntu bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/1489855) that happens to have finally been fixed in Ubuntu 19.10. There's nothing Rufus can do to fix Ubuntu ISOs where the casper scripts haven't been fixed.

Comment: @matohak: it is easy to make a 18.04 Rufus install persistent see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1126145/can-i-convert-a-live-ubuntu-usb-to-one-with-persistent-memory/1126305#1126305

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an ongoing [bug with UnetBootin](https://github.com/unetbootin/unetbootin/issues/90), it doesn't automatically add the boot flag.

I am not sure about the other software you have used but I can recommend you to use [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/). It's free software as well. Also it is the recommended software by the Ubuntu official guide for installing Ubuntu on a Windows PC.

Follow this [official tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1) step by step.

Comment: I got pass the bug using Rufus. However, Rufus itself seems to have a bug which doesn't allow live USB with persistence for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. As I wish to use the OS on-the-go, having a drive with no persistence would not be useful =(.

Comment: Once you are into the Ubuntu live OS you have more options to make it persistent. This question has been answered before [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051543/how-to-make-a-live-ubuntu-18-04-usb-with-a-persistent-storage-of-more-than-4gb).

Comment: Tried more options from the link. Yumi seems to work for my case.

Comment: Again, the 18.04 issue is not a Rufus bug. It's a Ubuntu bug. It's not Rufus' job to add extensive patching for buggy ISOs. If you are unhappy about this situation, you should ask the Ubuntu maintainers to retrofit the casper fix into the next 18.04 LTS refresh (if there is one planned).