# How to make a persistent USB/SD from Mac

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb, mac, persistence

I've been searching the internet for ages now and I haven't been able to find a way to make a persistent Ubuntu 20.04 USB from a Mac. All the articles seem to either be outdated or just say "now boot to it" at the end, and when I do, it doesn't work. The closest I've got is using these articles (https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview and https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/03/create-persistent-storage-live-usb-with.html)

1. Using Etcher to make a normal live USB
2. Booting to it, downloading mkusb and making a live 'persistent' USB
3. Booting to that USB and getting stuck at the loading page, and when I try recovery mode I get a kernel panic

I have a 2013 MacBook Air, loads of 8GB USB sticks, and a 16 GB SD card. If anyone could help me that would be amazing.

Comment: I use the dd CLI command just as I would on any Unix box to flash drives.   You don’t really need a GUI tool.

Answer (score 0):

### UNetbootin

Has a MacOS version, it can be downloaded here:

https://unetbootin.github.io/

Off the shelf persistence is limited to 4GB but it is easy to create a persistent partition of any size, see: [Can I convert a live Ubuntu USB to one with persistent memory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1126145/can-i-convert-a-live-ubuntu-usb-to-one-with-persistent-memory/1176695#1176695)